# Rewriting URLs and allowing multiple Query Strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs while still allowing multiple optional Query Strings.

For example, I know I can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php
```

Is it possible to allow more query strings to be passed so I could use something like `products/?page=1&foo=bar` and so on?

Thanks.

Edit: What I wanted was just the [QSA] at the end of the rule. Works like I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=[0-9]*&foo=bar$
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [L]
```

Or simply rewrite your condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=[0-9]*(&|$)
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but not exactly what I wanted. I've just found out that I can add [QSA] at the end of the rule and it works as I expected. Thanks anyway!